# Landing page to have both login and register

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am pretty new to Laravel. I am trying to customize the inbuilt Authentication System.

1)I want the Login form and Registration form on the same page

2) I want the above page to be displayed at localhost:8000 and not localhost:8000/auth/login and not as localhost:8000/auth/register

2)Change the form fields. (Login via username and not email, etc..)

What all needs to be configured for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
Just create a view (eg. home.blade.php) and insert the two forms.

```
<!-- Form 1 -->
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"> ... </form>
<!-- Form 2 -->
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/register') }}"> ... </form>
```

**2.** Edit your `routes.php` file

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return \View::make('home.blade.php'); 
});
```

**3.** To login via username edit the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` file and make the following changes in the `postLogin()` method

```
$credentials = $request->only('name', 'password');

...

return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('name', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'name' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
```

and change the login form in the view..

```
// Change this..
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
// to..
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
```

Comment: This is not the complete solution. No change in Users.php ? No change in Registrar.php ?

Comment: No.. You dont need to change these two files.